# Erlang, Function which return the lenghts of the lists?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to implement a function

```
llen(ListOfLists)
```

which returns a list containing the lengths of the lists in ListOfLists. Function should use lists:map/2.

Example:

```
1> funs:llen([[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5]]).
[3, 0, 2]
```

I know how to calculate length for one list:

```
list([]) -> 0;
list([_|T]) -> 1+list(T).
```

but i don't know how to do this for multiple lists using funs and lists.

Comment: `lists:map(fun erlang:length/1, [[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5]])`?

Comment: @Dogbert yes, ty a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

`lists:map/2` is a higher order function that applies a function for each element of a list. `erlang:length/1` is a function that returns the length of a list.

Apply `erlang:length/1` on each element of your list using `lists:map/2`:

```
lists:map(fun erlang:length/1, [[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

And when you get to *list comprehensions*:

```
53> L = [[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5]].
[[1,2,3],[],[4,5]]

54> [length(X) || X <- L].
[3,0,2]
```

A *list comprehension* is like a for-loop in other languages, and this one reads like:

```
length(X)  for   X in L
length(X)  ||    X <- L
```

The outer `[  ]` serves to gather up all the results into a list.

Comment: both solutions are good, but ty for list comprehensions explanation. It's useful.